# Building an LED matrix to plot mathematical curves

Tags: led

I've decided of building an LED matrix(10x10) to plot mathematical curves such as line, parabola, etc. I'm a total beginner so I just wanted to ask how to proceed about this.

At first, I thought of just joining the specific LED's to give the desired curve. But that would have been too naive , wouldn't it ?

So please help.

Comment: What is your thought about controlling the leds? Will it be manually by switches, will it be with digital gates, will it be with a microcontroller?

Comment: @alexan_e I have thought of controlling the LED's manually by switches

Comment: Then you will need 100 switches, one to control each LED individually plus 100 resistors, one for each led. Doesn't seem like a very efficient way to do it but it should be simple enough. In which particular part you need help?

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more how you expect it to work with just LEDs and switches. I'd have thought it impractical because you'd need a switch for each LED unless you were producing hardware that produced a row or column scan-output to give you a visual that looked "complete" rather than set-up a hundred switches to do what you want. Explain the user interface more.

Comment: @alexan_e I want to plot a curve(say equation of parabola y^2 = 4ax) ,in this I want to control the value of 'a' manually.

Comment: What's purpose of this device?  Are you trying to demonstrate how LEDs and switches work?  Or, are you trying to display mathematical curves to somebody to make them understand math better?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the open source hardware project Facecandy. Try modifying for your needs.Visit this link 
https://github.com/scanlime/fadecandy

[image]

**edit:**  the picture makes this answer less link-only

Comment: I want to make it from scratch